# Is this my ac switch in Toyota aygo old model

Tags: toyota, part-identification

[image]

Can you please tell if the highlighted one is the ac switch in my toyota aygo old model? The symbol shows that of a windshield vent. I cant find any other switch. Note that I bought a used car recently.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the manual but I am familiar with the symbols. The circled button is for the rear defrosters. To the right of your finger is the heat adjustment. When it is pointing to the blue dots the air conditioning is cooling, when pointing to the red it is heating.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a switch which indicates that air conditioning is on. Or which switch toggles between fan and ac?

Comment: @Suresh -  I don't see anything which is indicating there is A/C installed on your car. There's no switch present for it. If there was, I'd suggest it would be to the right of the red hazard switch.

Comment: @Paulster2 is correct. I just looked online and the AC Switch would go to the right of the hazard switch if equipped.

Comment: Ah, the good ole days, when men were men and giants roamed the earth. I remember when AC take rates were like 15% on trucks. In fact I remember when my employer offered a heater delete option (No heater, no air conditioning) for Hawaiian vehicles. Oh well. All good now. Just send money.